# Order the result of a comma separated string generated with STUFF

Tags: sql-server, order-by, csv

Given a schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo
(
    Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    Position int NOT NULL,
    Title varchar(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Foo VALUES
(1, 3,  'Title3'),
(2, 10, 'Title10'),
(3, 1,  'Title1'),
(4, 12, 'Title12'),
(5, 2,  'Title2');
```

I need to generate a comma separated string ordered by `Position`:

```
'M' + Id + ' AS [' + Title + ']'
```

Desired result:

```
M1 AS [Title1], M2 AS [Title10], M3 AS [Title3], M4 AS [Title10], M5 AS [Title12]
```

I've tried:

```
DECLARE @rows nvarchar(max);
SET @rows = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + ('M' + CAST(Id as varchar(10)) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(Title)) 
                   FROM Foo
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)') 
           ,1,1,'');

SELECT @rows;
```

But it builds the result ordered by `Id`:

```
M1 AS [Title3], M2 AS [Title10], M3 AS [Title1], M4 AS [Title12], M5 AS [Title2]
```

If I add `ORDER BY Id` to the `STUFF` expression:

```
DECLARE @rows nvarchar(max);
SET @rows = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + ('M' + CAST(Id as varchar(10)) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(Title)) 
                   FROM Foo
                   ORDER BY Position
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)') 
           ,1,1,'');

SELECT @rows;
```

Produces the next error:

> Msg 145 Level 15 State 1 Line 2
>   ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
>   +

I can use a subquery ordered by `Position`:

```
DECLARE @rows nvarchar(max);
SET @rows = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + ('M' + CAST(Id as varchar(10)) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(Title)) 
                   FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT Id, Position, Title FROM Foo ORDER BY Position) X
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)') 
           ,1,1,'');

SELECT @rows;

M1 AS [Title3], M2 AS [Title10], M3 AS [Title1], M4 AS [Title12], M5 AS [Title2]
```

But I wonder if there is another way to order the result without using a subquery. There are no duplicated titles.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f862c915ba4070d34fa6d7c3299976e3)*

Comment: i think you are asking part of your main problem,so not able to think why you will need such output.

Comment: To be clear the only role STUFF plays here is removing the surplus delimiter. The bulk of the generation is done by XML PATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) pointed out in comments, the error is produced because I'm using `SELECT DISTINCT`; and in this example it is not necessary. Also, `ORDER BY` position is fully valid if the distinct is removed.

If `DISTINCT` is removed the query returns the desired value:

> ```
> DECLARE @rows nvarchar(max);
> SET @rows = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ('M' + CAST(Id as varchar(10)) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(Title)) 
>                    FROM Foo
>                    ORDER BY Position
>             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
>             ).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)') 
>            ,1,1,'');
>
> SELECT @rows;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name)                                                                  |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |  M3 AS [Title1], M5 AS [Title2], M1 AS [Title3], M2 AS [Title10], M4 AS [Title12] |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3c951882a9b36438b120f021abad59ba)*

I recommend having a look at this article, recommended by [sp_BlitzErik](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32281/sp-blitzerik):

[Grouped Concatenation : Ordering and Removing Duplicates](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation-2)